# RegEx - Match optional groups

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing

I know RegEx is not the best way to scrape HTMLs, but this is it...
I have some something like:

```
<td> Writing: <a href="creator.php?c=CCh">Carlo Chendi</a>  Art: <a href="creator.php?c=LBo">Luciano Bottaro</a> </td>
```

And I need to match the Writing and Art parts. But it is not said they're there, and there could be other parts like Ink and Pencils...

How do I do this? I need to use pure RegEx, no additional Python libs.

Comment: It isn't "not the best way", it isn't a way. If I require you to hammer a nail with a noodle, the failure to accomplish it is my fault, not yours.

Comment: Yeah, right. Wouldn't do that if i wouldn't be somehow forced to do that way... unless you have a suggestion on how to read a html without additional libraries in Python...

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to sound harsh...I really don't need to read all the tags, just some specific ones, so  I think this can be done... I could be wrong though... thanks!

Comment: Would be sooooo good if, just for once, people weren't admonished for wanting to learn regular expressions. XML parsers are ridiculously heavy-weight for a lot of situations. Imagine admonishing any beginner from learning BASIC or C when they could learn Java or C# instead.. just sheer stupidity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite my previous answer, I changed my mind and would like NOT to have options/alternate, but get them all. So, this means that whatever is inside the TD tags have to be captured and properly classified.
I need to create a capture group optional, so that whatever is the layout, I can still retrieve the content.
It should work with this, i.e.:

```
<td>   Art: <a href="creator.php?c=GPe">Giuseppe Perego</a> </td>
<td> Writing: <a href="creator.php?c=CCh">Carlo Chendi</a>  Art: <a href="creator.php?c=LBo">Luciano Bottaro</a> </td>
<td>  Pencils: <a href="creator.php?c=JB">Jack Bradbury</a> Ink: <a href="creator.php?c=SSt">Steve Steere</a> </td>
<td>  Pencils: <a href="creator.php?c=JB">Jack Bradbury</a> Ink: <a href="creator.php?c=SSt">Steve Steere</a> </td>
<td> Writing: <a href="creator.php?c=DKi">Dick Kinney</a> Pencils: <a href="creator.php?c=TS">Tony Strobl</a> Ink: <a href="creator.php?c=SSt">Steve Steere</a> </td>
<td>  Pencils: <a href="creator.php?c=JB">Jack Bradbury</a> Ink: <a href="creator.php?c=SSt">Steve Steere</a> </td>
<td> Writing: <a href="creator.php?c=BKa">Bob Karp</a> Pencils: <a href="creator.php?c=AT">Al Taliaferro</a> Ink: <a href="creator.php?c=AH">Al Hubbard</a> </td>    
<td> Writing: <a href="creator.php?c=DKi">Dick Kinney</a> Pencils: <a href="creator.php?c=TS">Tony Strobl</a> Ink: <a href="creator.php?c=SSt">Steve Steere</a> </td>
<td> Writing: <a href="creator.php?c=VLo">Vic Lockman</a>  Art: <a href="creator.php?c=KWr">Kay Wright</a> </td>
<td> Writing: <a href="creator.php?c=MGa">Michele Gazzarri</a>  Art: <a href="creator.php?c=GPe">Giuseppe Perego</a> </td>
```

I created:

```
<td>\ {1,3}(?:(?:Writing: <a href="creator\.php\?c=[^>"]*?">(.*?)?</a>).*?)?(?:(?:Pencils: <a href="creator\.php\?c=[^>"]*?">(.*?)?</a>\ ))?(?:(?:Ink: <a href="creator\.php\?c=[^>"]*?">(.*?)?</a>))?(?:(?:Art: <a href="creator\.php\?c=[^>"]*?">(.*?)?</a>))?\ {1,3}</td>
```

And it looks like it is working!

I'd really appreciate someone to check and validate my effort.

Comment: as a second thought, i could have simply retrieved the names between tags and then  strip them in Python...but i enjoyed!

Comment: The difficulty for you here is dealing with multiple matches. Let's say you have both Writing and Art between `td`s... you will not know which match number to inspect. I would suggest a multiple step process. First, extract everything within the `td`s. Then, inside a loop, match globally (i.e. return one result at a time). But you seem to be picking up the syntax of regular expressions okay.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there are two patterns to recognise.

1. your keywords exist within a <td>...</td>
2. your keywords are followed by a <a>...</a> section

So.. first extract everything within <td>s... (psuedo code)

```
while ( match( "<td[^>]*>(.*?)</td[^>]*>" ) ) {
    inner = match[1];
    ...
}
```

The `(.*?)` means match non-greedily, i.e. match the minimum possible. Otherwise you would match everything from the first `<td>` to the *last* `</td>` (instead of the next `</td>`).

Then you can move on to processing the `inner` portion!

Answer (score 1):

```
regex = re.compile("(\w+):")
regex.findall(yourString); // returns an array of matching elements
```

You can test it [here](http://www.pythonregex.com/)

PS: I highly recommend you to go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1):

I created this eventually:

```
(Art:|Pencils:|Ink:|Writing:){0,4}.<a href="creator\.php\?c=[^">]*?\"\>(?P<Name>.*?)\</a\>
```

that looks like it is working... maybe it can be polished a bit. I'm a starter you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can match optional things in regexs using a ? after the optional part.  ? will match either 0 or 1 occurrences of a sub-expression.